# Is there a Shopify chatbot integration that gives the implementer control over the chatbot box size?

Tags: css, shopify, integration, chatbot, hubspot

Is there a known chatbot that integrates with Shopify that gives the user access to CSS properties such as height and width of the chatbot window?

I tried and failed to modify Hubspot's chatbot size configuration. Looks like it's inaccessible to me.

I have been failing to find a chatbot that integrates with Shopify and gives the user control over the size of the window that appears on the page.

Because these chatbots appear on the end site inside an iframe there is no way to modify their css afterwards.

Thanks for your help Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

[Kommunicate](https://www.kommunicate.io) allows overriding the CSS properties and change height, width, color, etc

```js
// Todo: replace <APP_ID> with your account APP_ID from Kommunicate
       (function(d, m){
        var kommunicateSettings = 
            {"appId":"<APP_ID>","popupWidget":true,"automaticChatOpenOnNavigation":true, onInit: function() {
var style = document.createElement('style');
var classSettings = ".change-kommunicate-iframe-height{height:100%!important;width: 390px!important;box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1.5rem 2rem!important;max-height:calc(100% - 30px) !important;}";
style.type = 'text/css';
style.innerHTML = classSettings;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);

KommunicateGlobal.document.getElementById('mck-sidebox-launcher').addEventListener('click',function(){ var testClick = parent.document.getElementById("kommunicate-widget-iframe"); testClick.classList.add("change-kommunicate-iframe-height"); });

KommunicateGlobal.document.getElementById('km-chat-widget-close-button').addEventListener('click',function(){ var testClick = parent.document.getElementById("kommunicate-widget-iframe"); testClick.classList.remove("change-kommunicate-iframe-height"); });
 } };
        var s = document.createElement("script"); s.type = "text/javascript"; s.async = true;
        s.src = "https://widget.kommunicate.io/v2/kommunicate.app";
        var h = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]; h.appendChild(s);
        window.kommunicate = m; m._globals = kommunicateSettings;
    })(document, window.kommunicate || {});
```

You can override any CSS property using Kommunicate.customizeWidgetCss function.
Refer to [chat bot widget customization docs](https://docs.kommunicate.io/docs/web-customization#customize-chat-widget-by-using-css)

Instructions on how to add Kommunicate chatbot to Shopify is available [here](https://www.kommunicate.io/blog/shopify-chatbot/)